# Что такое зависимые слова и всегда ли они есть в предложении?

Tags: подчинительная-связь

Объясните, что такое зависимые слова? Всегда ли в предложении присутствуют слова, которые можно назвать зависимыми? Как их найти?

Например: Озеро глубокое. Вода темная, прохладная. Есть ли в этих предложениях зависимые слова?

Answer (score 1):

Зависимое слово - это слово, к которому задается вопрос от главного слова. Например, в словосочетании "умный парень" слово "парень" - главное слово. Парень какой? Умный. Это зависимое слово. Его род, число и особенно падеж ЗАВИСЯТ от главного слова. В словосочетании "читаю книгу" главное слово "читаю". Читаю что? Книгу. Это зависимое слово. Быстро еду. Еду как? Быстро. И т. д.

Comment: Про задавание вопроса - как-то непрофессионально.  "Умный парень".  Умный ***кто***?  Парень.  Получается, что "парень" - зависимое.

Answer (score -1):

Главное слово - это то слово, от которого мы задаем вопрос зависимому. Например: *плыть на лодке*. *Плыть* - главное слово. *На лодке* (плыть на чем?) - зависимое.