# Верно ли написание НЕ с причастием?

Tags: частица-не, причастия

«Личность – не укладывающаяся в рамки общепризнанных норм». Верно ли написание НЕ с причастием?

Answer (score 1):

(1) **Он личность, не укладывающаяся в рамки общепризнанных норм.** (2) **Вы – неприспособленные к жизни цветы.**

Чем-то похожи эти выражения, но пишутся по-разному, хотя это причастные формы глагола и в обоих случаях **есть зависимое слово**. Именно это настораживает и вызывает вопросы.

Общее в них то, что смысл действия здесь **переносный**: в рамки никто и никого не укладывает и к жизни не приспосабливает.

Но в первом случае переносное значение заключено в самом устойчивом глагольном сочетании, а во втором мы имеем пару **причастие (прямое значение глагола) и отпричастное прилагательное (переносное значение)**.

А прямое значение глагола –  это "сделать пригодным для употребления, использования в каких-л. целях". Для исключения этого значения **причастие переходит в прилагательное и НЕ пишется слитно.**

Comment: "Неприспособленные к жизни цветы" — здесь прилагательное. А вот прилагательного "неукладывающийся" нет.

Comment: Грамма: Различаются в написании причастия с частицей не, имеющие зависимые слова, и прилагательные с приставкой не-, возникшие на базе этих причастий; ср.: не приспособленные для эксплуатации в зимнее время установки ('никто не приспособил к зимним условиям') — неприспособленный к жизни человек ('не умеющий приспособиться, непрактичный'); не организованные вовремя занятия ('никто не организовал') — неорганизованные дети ('разболтанные, недисциплинированные'); не выдержанный необходимое время заварной чай ('не выдержали нужное время') — невыдержанный в спорах человек ('вспыльчивый, горячий').

Comment: Прилагательные имеют отличное от причастий значение (менее связанное с мотивирующим глаголом) и свободно могут заменяться в предложении синонимичными прилагательными, что невозможно для причастий, имеющих зависимые слова. Кроме того, эти образования различаются и грамматически: после страдательных причастий, например, всегда можно поставить вопрос кем?, так как эти причастия управляют дополнением в творительном падеже (творительный субъекта, деятеля): не приспособленные (кем?) для эксплуатации в зимнее время установки; не организованные (кем?) вовремя занятия.

Comment: В случаях же с прилагательными постановка такого вопроса невозможна. 
Это же различие наблюдается и в кратких формах; ср.: чай не выдержан — человек невыдержан.  (http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.56)

Answer (score 0):

На каком основании там тире? Обычный причастный оборот.

**Личность, не укладывающаяся в рамки общепризнанных норм.**

Comment: ну там еще были слова.....Раздельно пишется? Есть зависимые слова?

Comment: Раздельно пишется не с причастиями, имеющими при себе зависимые слова.

Comment: я тоже об этом думала....а тут Рамки - завис.слово?

Comment: Что такое зависимые слова? - См. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/33712/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82

Comment: непрочитанная книга - книга какая? непрочитанная...?? Это зависимое слово, судя по этой ссылке??? Данное причастие пишется слитно, как раз потому, что не имеет зависимых слов! Не прочитанная мной (кем) книга - зависимое - мной...

Comment: Нужно понять, что от чего зависит. Книга (какая?) непрочитанная. Непрочитанная - зависимое слово, но у слова непрочитанная нет зависимый слов.

Comment: но ведь она попадает под правило Нет зависимого слова - пишется слитно!

Comment: в моем случае - не укладывающаяся во что? в рамки?

Comment: Не укладывающаяся (во что?) в рамки. Причастие укладывающаяся имеет зависимое  слово "в рамки".

Comment: ок. спасибо!!!!!